# Call a C# webmethod from Ajax

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I need to make a call to a webmethod that is defined in this class

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" Class="emt7anReyady.myService" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace emt7anReyady
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class myService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
        public void test()
        {
            Context.Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com");
        }
    }
}
```

and I have make an Ajax call like this one

```
function getData() {
                 $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     url: "myService.asmx/test",
                     data: "{}",
                     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                     dataType: "json",
                     success: function () {
                         alert("succesed")
                     },
                     failure: function () {
                         alert("faild")
                     }
                 });
             }
```

the problem that the call is failed and in the chrome console I get this !!
[image: Error Image]

Comment: Did you try putting ; at the end of your alert statement. Also, Please mention error because in image its not easily readable. One more suggestion, use single quotes instead of double in your ajax call.

Comment: that's where the problem is that the error isn't readable and for the ; haven't change anything !

Answer (score 1):

You are getting ThreadAbort response due to using of `Response.Redirect`.

It is not exactly clear what you are trying to achieve with this code - if you want proxy some other site you need to read and forward response...

Comment: I need to do some login and then transfer to a local page say per example 'Thanks.aspx' but I got the same error

Answer (score 0):

It is because of Response.Redirect you are using in your WebMethod. If you really want to redirect to some other page, do it from the success block.

```
.
.

success: function () {
                     window.open('http://www.google.com');
                 },
.
.
```

you can also make use of document.location instead of window.open